# Is there no such thing as species?

Tags: evolution, species

If you recreated intermediate species between every species on the evolutionary tree, would every species be able to reproduce with each other through a series of intermediates? Would this blur the concept of "species"?

Comment: Yes it is a concept like Fuzzy logic. It exists but its 'border' is not at all clear cut.

Comment: Like your head-hairs and beards can-not be distinguished with 1 clear-cut line; yet your head-hair and beard is not the same; they have some own features... beards grow-up only on and after adolescence.

Comment: 'reproductive barrier' is a main, but not the only criterion to define a species.  It is used mostly for the animals. In case of other-kingdoms; only vegetatively reproducing strains, reproductive isolation could not be judged.  Rather we have to depend on other sorts of characteristics; from macroscopic through biochemical to molecular-genetic. In certain cases, especially for microbes, to define a species is really difficult; and sometimes instead species, directly the specimen-number ( like certain particular collection-number or culture number) is preferred.

Comment: Without need to recreate any species, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species offers a real life examples of the situation proposed by the OP. It challenges the concept of species somehow, but also sheds light on the process of speciation.